# ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently dealing with two problems which I do not know how to fix. I would appreciate any help :)

my first problem was: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. This was my code below

```
    public void AddStudentDetails()
    {
        StudentDetailsDAL ASDDAL = new StudentDetailsDAL(database);
        int studentID = int.Parse(dgvSummerSchool.Rows[StartingRowNumber].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        String forename = dgvSummerSchool.Rows[StartingRowNumber].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        String surname = dgvSummerSchool.Rows[StartingRowNumber].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        DateTime doB = DateTime.Parse(dgvSummerSchool.Rows[StartingRowNumber].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        ASDDAL.AddStudentDetails(studentID, forename, surname, doB);
        MessageBox.Show("The row has been successfully added");; 
    }
```

I read some answers which stated to add the column numbers but once I include this

```
dgvSummerSchool.ColumnCount = 4;
```

(below the line:

```
StudentDetailsDAL ASDDAL new StudentDetails(database)
```

I get the error below:

> ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is `StartingRowNumber`?

Comment: How many rows does your datagridview have? What is the value of `StartingRowNumber` ?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, it's a variable set to 0 used as a counter. I'm realizing now that's probably the issue.
I can include the method it is used in if that helps at all

Comment: If you have a data bound grid why do you pull the values not directly from the source? Is anything displayed in the grid?

Comment: I am going to be pulling multiple tables into the grid via a combo box selection so I can't direction pull it in

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. The error message is clear and self explanatory.